# Comparing Json Template with JSON Response

Tags: java

<sup>(The following has been edited to make it understandable.)</sup>

We want to compare an actual JSON object with an expected JSON object, with the complication that the JSON objects may contain other JSON objects. We are using the `net.sf.JSON API` for this. We have tried the following approaches:

1. We have tried the JSON objects' keys to lists (to preserve the keys' order) and then indexes of the keys in the lists.
2. We have tried adding (flattening) the keys and values in the JSON objects into a pair of Map objects.  In this case, we had problems with duplicate keys in the nested JSON objects.  We addressed this by making the values in the Map  lists of values from the JSON objects.

After discussion with my team, I need to modify my approach as follows:

<sup>(The following has not been edited ...)</sup>

Now I wanna compare the key and values in result JSON and expected JSON (must need to check the format) while traversing each key in result JSON parallelly want to check same(key and value) in Expected JSON.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you post the code that you have written already

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are preserving the order of the keys in the JSON objects because the order is important to the meaning of the JSON, then you are abusing JSON.  The JSON specs make it clear that the order of the key in a JSON object *should not be significant*.  A lot of JSON implementations will not preserve key order when deserializing, and ... indeed ... may not be able of representing the order.

If you have made that conceptual mistake, you should fix it before it is too late (!).  If you need to represent order, use a JSON array to do that.

Assuming that you aren't trying to do that, then here is a simple approach to encoding the JSON object trees as a `Map` objects.  Instead of using a `Map<String, List<Object>>` where the keys are JSON keys, use a `Map<String, Object>` where the keys are formed by concatenating the keys in the *path* from the JSON root; e.g.

```
    {a: {b : "c",
         d : "e"}}
```

becomes the `Map`.

```
    {"a.b" = "c",
     "a.d" = "e}
```

Now you don't have to deal with lists of values, the ordering of those, or other problems that you have probably encountered.  Instead you can simply sort the map's entry set on the composite keys, and compare them looking for missing or extra entries, or entries with the wrong value.